# ITemplate, the reason for leaving InstantiateIn(Control container)

Tags: asp.net

I'm implementing the `ITemplate` interface in `ListView` control. If i realize it for `ItemTemplate` in my custom class, everything will be OK. I mean, the runtime will invoke InstantiateIn when i use

```
ListView.ItemTemplate = new CustomClass(); 

CustomClass :ITemplate 
{
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        HtmlTable table = CreateHeader();
        container.Controls.Add(table);
    }
    ...
}
```

But i want to do the same with `ListView.LayoutTemplate`. In this case, the runtime invokes InstantiateIn only one time, but every next update it leaves my method. What is the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

Layout template says how the root container does look like, it is not per item thing.

Comment: I have to change my LayoutTemplate after clicking different buttons.
And My LayoutTemplate has a header for the whole ListView. I have to change it, it depends on button. Also i have two custom classes with implementations of ITemplate (one for ItemTemplate and one for LayoutTemplate). I am going to realise the folowing behaviour:
1). If i click Button1
ListView.ItemTemplate = new CustomItemClass1();
ListView.LayoutTemplate = new CustomLayuotClass1();
2).If i click Button2
ListView.ItemTemplate = new CustomItemClass2();
ListView.LayoutTemplate = new CustomLayuotClass2();

Comment: Are you doing this in Load event? wouldn't be enough to have just different css style on ListView?

Answer (score 0):

I have to change my LayoutTemplate after clicking different buttons.

And My LayoutTemplate has a header for the whole ListView. I have to change it, it depends on button.

Also i have two custom classes with implementations of ITemplate (one for ItemTemplate and one for LayoutTemplate). I am going to realise the folowing behaviour:

1). If i click Button1

```
ListView.ItemTemplate = new CustomItemClass1();
ListView.LayoutTemplate = new CustomLayuotClass1();
```

2). If i click Button2

```
ListView.ItemTemplate = new CustomItemClass2();
ListView.LayoutTemplate = new CustomLayuotClass2();
```

But i can't see my header of LayoutTemplate more, then one time.